# string extraction in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table named TP_GEO_ASSN and the fields are ID , GEO_DETAILS. The values of fields are given below

ID                   GEO_DETAILS

1                    INDIA | KARNATAKA | BANGALORE | RELIANCE SUPER MARKET

2                        INDIA | KERALA | CALICUT | EXPRESS SUPER MARKET

3                      INDIA | WEST BENGAL | KOLKATA | MORE SUPER MARKET

.                 .

.                 .

.               .

my problem is i need to write a procedure and it extracts GEO_DETAILS values into string variable .
 I need to extract values between the pipeline symbol (|) for example

INDIA | KARNATAKA | BANGALORE | RELIANCE SUPER MARKET

I need to extract INDIA , KARNATAKA , BANGALORE ,RELIANCE SUPER MARKET and
i need to pass these values separately from stored procedure example INDIA in one variable , KARNATAKA in another variable and so on
How can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Declare 4 variables and use the below query to store those variables

```
select trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COL_NAME, '[^|]+', 1, 1)),
        trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COL_NAME, '[^|]+', 1, 2)),
        trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COL_NAME, '[^|]+', 1, 3)),
        trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COL_NAME, '[^|]+', 1, 4))   into var1, var2, var3, var4   from <YOUR_TABLE_NAME>;
```

Var1 will contain INDIA, var2 will contain KARNATAKA and so on.. Then pass the variables into your procedure as per your need.